# How are discrete convolutions applied to real world signals?

Tags: discrete-signals, convolution

I'm in a position where I need to practically apply a filter to digitally sampled input data in realtime (from an ADC or otherwise). In other words, a [Discrete Convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution). However, after reviewing the literature, it struck me that this operation requires predicting the future sample points of the input function.

The discrete convolution of an input function and some filter of length $2M+1$ is defined as

$$ (f*g)[n]=\sum_{m=-M}^M f[n-m]g[m] $$

Of course this implies, for instance, that

$$(f*g)[0] = f[M]g[-M] + f[M-1]g[-M+1] + ... $$

That is, the zeroth output index of the convolution is a function of some $M$ future data points of the input function.

In practice how is this done in *realtime* as data samples are captured by some source? At a glance I can only square this by the operation inherently producing a *delay* in the output $(f*g)[n]$ of length $2M + 1)$, or the size of the filter function $g[n]$.

This being a direct result of the dependency that the convolution not being applied to
the input signal prior to first sampling sufficient data points such that the summation over all points $[-M,M]$ can be applied.

Of course I think this is incorrect, but *practically* I remain unsure.

Answer (score 3):

The problem starts with *your* definition of the output of your length-$(2M+1)$ filter, which *you* define as a *noncausal* filter: the current output depends on past, current, *and* future input values.  If you change the definition of your filter to be a *causal* filter, the problem  disappears.

**Example:** Choose $M=1$.  Your filter is a short-term average whose output is the *average* of the immediately past, the current, and the immediately next future value.  Thus, $H(z) = \left.\left.\frac 13 \right( z + 1 + z^{-1}\right)$ and so we have the problem you found. But change the definition to the average of the current input value and the two immediately-past input values, and $H(z)$ becomes $\left.\left.\frac 13 \right( 1 + z^{-1}+z^{-2}\right)$ and the problem disappears.